# Tensorflow 1.14 equivalent of Tensorflow 2.0 model.trainable_variables

Tags: python, tensorflow

How can I replace Tensorflow 2.0 `model.trainable_variables` in Tensorflow.1.14 (https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/guide/effective_tf2) ?

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/trainable_variables

Comment: I tried and it fails. It concerns all trainable variables, not those of the model only.

Comment: I posted an answer. I assume that it should help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have two `tf.keras.Model`:

```
model_1 = tf.keras.Sequential([tf.keras.layers.Dense(100, name="model_1/dense1")])
model_1.build(input_shape=(None, 50))
model_2 = tf.keras.Sequential([tf.keras.layers.Dense(100, name="model_2/dense1")])
model_2.build(input_shape=(None, 50))
```

You can obtain the trainable variables of the first model like this:

```
model_1_trainable = [variable for variable in tf.trainable_variables() if variable.name.startswith("model_1")]
```